# Swift -how to handle Firebase Database Error Codes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is `FIRAuthErrorCode/AuthErrorCode` to handle `Authentication` errors.

There is `FIRStorageErrorCode/StorageErrorCode` to handle `Storage` errors.

I looked through the docs but I can't find anything for `Database` errors. Does anything exist? A link or an example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like theres much to handle like storage and auth since the only error I could handle had a code=1.

I assume you mean error handling for something like:

```
Database.database().reference().child("RootValue")
    .setValue("Some String") 
{ (err, ref) in 
    //Handle error here
}
```

The only way I could get an error to show up is when having the database rules as writes only allowed when authenticated which returned the error:

```
Error 
Domain=com.firebase
Code=1 
"Permission denied"
UserInfo={ NSLocalizedDescription=Permission denied }
```

I tried disconnecting from the internet, but that just output an error to the console after a while. The completion closure was never called.

I also tried setting an illegal value to the database, but that doesn't call the closure with an error either. Instead it throws an exception and crashes the app which doesn't seem appropriate.

```
Database.database().reference().child("RootValue").setValue(Data())
```

Throws the exception

```
An uncaught exception was raised
2020-10-25 00:14:44.338071-0400 [General] (setValue:withCompletionBlock:) Cannot store object of type _NSZeroData at . Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.
```

I found a [constants file](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseDatabase/Sources/Constants/FConstants.m) that may help with transaction write errors if thats what you're looking for. I've included the bottom of the file which seems to be the most helpful part.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Error handling constants

NSString *const kFErrorDomain = @"com.firebase";
NSUInteger const kFAuthError = 1;
NSString *const kFErrorWriteCanceled = @"write_canceled";

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Validation Constants

NSUInteger const kFirebaseMaxObjectDepth = 1000;
const unsigned int kFirebaseMaxLeafSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // 10 MB

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Transaction Constants

NSUInteger const kFTransactionMaxRetries = 25;
NSString *const kFTransactionTooManyRetries = @"maxretry";
NSString *const kFTransactionNoData = @"nodata";
NSString *const kFTransactionSet = @"set";
NSString *const kFTransactionDisconnect = @"disconnect";
```